# Describing leaves of a tree with an underbrace using pstree/pstricks

Tags: pstricks, trees, pst-tree

I'd like to have a discription for some of the leaves. It doesn't need to be an underbace, if somebody has better graphical suggestions... :)

Consider this example:

```
\pstree[levelsep=35pt]{\Tcircle{$\rho$}}
  {
    \Tf*
    \Tf*
    \psset{linestyle=none}  \Tr{$\cdots$} \psset{linestyle=solid}
    \Tf*
    \Tf*
    \Tf*
    \psset{linestyle=none}  \Tr{$\cdots$} \psset{linestyle=solid}
    \Tf*

  }
```

I'm thinking about something like this, which of won't work that way:

```
\pstree[levelsep=35pt]{\Tcircle{$\rho$}}
  {
    \underbrace{
      \Tf*
      \Tf*
      \psset{linestyle=none}  \Tr{$\cdots$} \psset{linestyle=solid}
      \Tf*
    }_{n \mbox{trees}}
    \underbrace{
      \Tf*
      \Tf*
      \psset{linestyle=none}  \Tr{$\cdots$} \psset{linestyle=solid}
      \Tf*
    }_{n \mbox{trees}}
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every tree works like a node. SO you can name the node to use it later. The brace is drawn with `\psbrace`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-tree}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}
\pstree[levelsep=35pt]{\Tcircle{$\rho$}}
  {
    \Tf*[name=first]
    \Tf*
    {\psset{linestyle=none}  \Tr{$\cdots$}}
    \Tf*[name=second]
    \Tf*
    \Tf*
    {\psset{linestyle=none}  \Tr{$\cdots$}}
    \Tf*
  }
\psbrace*[linecolor=blue,ref=lC]([nodesep=5pt,angle=-165]first)([nodesep=5pt,angle=-15]second){\rotatebox{90}{$n$ trees}}
\end{document}​
```

Comment: Instead of setting & resetting the `linestyle`, use grouping to modify it locally.

Comment: Hope you don't mind, I edited your answer a little. Roll back if you don't approve.

Comment: @Werner: I had to go yesterday. Thanks for the very good improvements.

Comment: I tried to do the same again, but with \Tfan instead of \Tf this time. But somehow it doesn't look fine. Could you explain the part with `angle`? How did you find these numbers?

Comment: After some googeling, I decided that this is a seperate question, so I asked it [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43678/offset-for-node-psbrace-around-nodes).

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pst-tree,pstricks-add}
\begin{document}

\pstree[levelsep=1.2cm]{\Tcircle{$\rho$}}{
    \Tf*[name=first]
    \Tf*
    \Tn{\ldots}
    \Tf*[name=second]
    \Tf*
    \Tf*
    \Tn{\ldots}
    \Tf*}
\psbrace*[linecolor=blue,ref=tC,rot=90,nodesep=2mm]([angle=-165]first)([angle=-15]second){Text II}
\end{document}
```

[image]