# Offset for node - psbrace around nodes

Tags: pstricks, pst-tree

I already asked in the question [Describing leaves of a tree with an underbrace using pstree/pstricks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39496/describing-leaves-of-a-tree-with-an-underbrace-using-pstree-pstricks) how to use a underbrace. Now I'd like to use `\Tfan` instead of `\Tf`, but the trick with the angle doesn't seem to work there (I also don't really understand why it's working with `\Tf`). I have to attach the `psbrace` not at the center of the nodes, but with a bit of offset - the `psbrace` should be a bit longer.

Herbert Voß provides a solution in this [maillist post](http://tug.org/mailman/htdig/pstricks/2010/008088.html), unfortunately I don't understand the methods used there and I can't manage to adopt them to my problem. He suggests basically suggests two methods.

One is to replace `\rnode{A}{$a$}` by `\rnode[bc]{A}{$a$\vphantom{gt}}`. But I couldn't manage to get this working also for horizontal space as desired.

The second method is to connect the `psbrace` not to `(A)` but to `(!\psGetNodeCenter{A} A.x A.y .2 sub)`. How is this called? How is the syntax of `!whatever` working? How could I adopt this?

[image: Output for minimal example]

```
\documentclass[english]{article}

\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{pst-tree}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}(1,-5)
    \pstree[levelsep=50pt,treesep=12pt]{\Tcircle{ }} {
        \skiplevel { 
          \Tf[name=firstleaf]{}
          \Tf{}
          {\psset{linestyle=none}  \Tr{$\cdots$} }
          \Tf[name=lastleaf]{}
        }

        \tspace{1.5cm}

        \pstree{\Tr{ }}{\Tfan[name=firstantree]}
        {\psset{linestyle=none}  \Tr{$\cdots$} }
        \pstree{\Tr{ }}{\Tfan[name=lastantree]}
    }
    \psbrace*[ref=tC,rot=90,nodesep=5pt]([angle=-165]firstleaf)([angle=-15]lastleaf){leaves} 

    \psbrace*[rot=90,ref=tC,nodesep=5pt,nodesepA=-5pt](firstantree)(lastantree){subrees}

    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
\psbrace*[rot=90,ref=tC,nodesep=5pt,nodesepA=-5pt]%
  ([Xnodesep=-1.5em]firstantree)([Xnodesep=1.5em]lastantree){subrees}
```

Comment: This method I didn't present ;-)

Comment: Wow, great! Thanks! This was excactly the option I was searching for.

Answer (score 6):

The following answer perhaps should be a comment, but it's too big.

Why don't you ask this question at the mailing list? `pstricks` accepts different kinds of coordinate input. Normally you use `(x,y)`, but you can use other input methods like `(! x y )`

A small collection is shown below:

- `(x,y)` -- normal Cartesian input
- `(r;a)` -- r=radius; a=angle -- polar coordinates
- `(! x y)` -- postscript notation.  Here the coordinates will be computed at the postscript level
- `(* x {f(x)})` -- use a function to compute the y coordinate related to the x coordinate
- `(Nodename)` -- use a defined node
- `( x1,y1 | x2,y2 )` use the x coordinate of the first group and the y coordinate of the second one. More complicated calculations are possible.

There are a lot of other possibilities shown in the documentation. However I don't want to show everything here.

The command `\psGetNodeCenter` accepts one mandatory argument, a node. The command takes the node and allows to handle the x and y coordinates separately. This command works only inside PostScript, so you must use the coordinate form `(! x y)`. The syntax itself follows the [Reverse Polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation). An example: addition of two numbers for the x coordinate and a single number for y

```
(! 2.2 3.4 add 5)
```

that's the equivalent of `x=2.2+3.4=5.6` and `y=5`, so the final point is  `(5.6,5)`.

Comment: (A bit off topic...) Well if I write to the mailing list, there is easy system to give reputation points afterwards! :)  Seriously, of course I could write to the mail list, but aren't all the questions from here also possible questions for the mailing list?

Comment: Do you know that HV has defined algebraic-algebraic notation `(+x,f(x))` in the PSTricks' core `pstricks.tex`?

Comment: @ClickMe: Does it work?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: In my experience: NO. :-)

Comment: I think it should be written as `(+x,{f(x)})` because I successfully do it.