# Calculating coordinates with postscript

Tags: pstricks, calculations

I want to calculate coordinates for some lines using `pstricks`. How can I do this?

**Example:**

I want something like

```
(0.5*cos(45) + 8, 0.5*sin(45) + 8)
```

and use coordinate pairs like this one to `draw` lines in between.

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43678/offset-for-node-psbrace-around-nodes/43718#43718

Comment: Ok...the (! x y) notation is working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't clear if you want to do the calculation in TeX or PostScript, in PostScript that would be

```
0.5 45 cos mul 8 add 0.5 45 sin mul 8 add
```

as you can check by typing to gs (or any other PostScript interpreter):

```
GS>0.5 45 cos mul 8 add 0.5 45 sin mul 8 add pstack
8.35355377
8.35355377
GS<2>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I want to do the calculations in PostScript, but don't know how to implement it, as `\psline(0.5 45 cos mul 8 add,0.5 45 sin mul 8 add)(0,0)` isn't working.

Comment: Try `\psline(!0.5 45 cos mul 8 add 0.5 45 sin mul 8 add)(0,0)`.